# How do I add hover styles on map area co-ordinates?

Tags: html

I have problem adding styles on area tag.

HTML Code :

```
<p>
        <img name="usaMap" src="images/animal-map.png" usemap="#animalMap" width="100%">
    </p>

    <map name="animalMap" id="animalMap">
        <area alt="" title="home" href="http://google.com.au" shape="poly" coords="733,591,735,643,808,642,801,584" class="area" />
        <area alt="" title="information" href="#" shape="poly" coords="676,700,684,790,759,785,754,707" class="area"/>
        <area alt="" title="tree" href="#" shape="poly" coords="540,280,558,334,654,323,639,268" class="area"/>
        <area alt="" title="foodcourt" href="#" shape="poly" coords="300,389,384,385,378,449,309,449" class="area"/>
        <area alt="" title="exit" href="#" shape="poly" coords="465,657,625,658,614,753,474,747" class="area"/>
    </map>
```

CSS Code:

```
.area:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Styles are not working on area tag.
I found one good link for adding style with jQuery now
http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html.

Comment: yes you are right . Thanks for your help !